# Sed command in unix is not working on file size greater than 3GB

Tags: unix, sed

Sed command is not working in Unix for file size greater that 3GB, to remove carriage return and new line character from the file.

I am trying to remove the new line character from a pipe delimited file.

code:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n|/|/g'   File.txt
```

It's a pipe delimited file so I am first searching for the end of line then I am replacing the new line character with a pipe.

Sample Input :

```
Test|A|B|C
|D
```

After the replace - Expected Output :

```
Test|A|B|C|D
```

Sed command is  working normally on all the files whose size is less than 3 GB, but not file files with bigger size.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Added the sample input and desired output

Comment: Check ulimits. Also check free diskspace. Also try to create new file instead of replace inline.

Comment: What kind of unix and which sed and version? AFAIK GNU sed doesn't has such a limitation

Comment: If you want to edit a 3GB file with the `-i` option, you need 3GB free space in the same directory as the 3GB file. If you load a 3GB file into memory (with command `N`), you will also need 3GB of free memory/swap.

Comment: Yes , i need to overwrite the same file . Is there any other command in unix  which can solve this purpose . I am not sure about the unix and sed version . 
If i create a new file how will i merge the file?

Comment: I would try this: 1) Split the file into chunks of some 1M lines, 2) Run `sed` on each, 3) Merge back.

Comment: Since you're a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I can imagine what fault you get, but note that you are only providing an interpretation ("does not work"), but not the actual observations, like e.g. the error output.

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed standards for units https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units specifically using capital **G** for *"giga"* and **B** for *"bytes"* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte , because **b** refers to *"bits"* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your sed command reads the whole file into memory first:

```sed
:a        # label a
N         # add next line to pattern space
$!ba      # if not on last line ($!) branch to label a
```

This will eventually fail with sufficiently large input, because pattern space is held in main memory.

Given the simple replacement you need, doing the replacement on pairs of lines would enough, e.g.:

```
:a        # label a
N         # add next line to pattern space
s/\n|/|/  # substitute new-line pipe by pipe
ta        # if last substitution was successful branch to label a
P         # print first line of pattern space
D         # delete first line of pattern space
```

As a one-liner:

```
sed -n ':a; N; s/\n|/|/; ta; P; D' File.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. for the help . this seems to be working with 4.4 GB file